# Calculate average annual growth rate per group in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel file with columns as below  that shows yearly turnover data for customers(real file has thousands of customers):

```
  customer   year   turnover  
 ---------- ------ ---------- 
       124   2018       8912  
       124   2019        324  
       124   2020       1235  
       533   2019      32498  
       533   2020      34599  
       272   2018        123  
       272   2019        534  
       272   2020        475
```

I want to calculate the average annual growth rate in turnover per customer , to get something as below ( the growth rates are made up and don't match up to the actual rates):

```
  customer   average_annual_growth_rate  
 ---------- ---------------------------- 
       124   -23%                        
       533   12%                         
       272   35%
```

I thought i could do this be generating a pivot table with the source data, creating two columns with turnover, then changing the second one to show the value as % difference from previous. However I can't calculate the average annual rate per customer this way. the pivot looks like this:

[image: pivot]

Has anybody done something like this in the past? creating an average annual growth rate where the number of years varies between customers?

can you assist with this? thank you!

Comment: How are you calculating the results you are showing in your textual table (not the screenshot) for the three customers:  `-23%, 12%, 35%`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld those are just some dummy numbers i made up

Comment: It would be useful to have your expected numbers.  It seems you are asking for an average of the annual growth rate of turnover per customer.  But without expected numbers, it is not clear to me if you want to have the first year cited as the baseline; or the year before with a zero value. I also wonder if what you want might be better expressed by the compound annual growth rate, where  only the first and last year are compared. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood your question, I think your a close to the solution. After creating your pivot table, insert Customers as rows and Turnover% as values. Then click on the Turnover% button and select "Value Field Settings"

[image: IMG:]

On the window that opens, select Average then click OK. The average turnover% per customer will be shown on the pivot table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. However there are cases when a turnover value for one year is 0, and the next year is non-0. This causes the percentage to display a DIV/0! error. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @JiangLi You need to cater for those cases. See the image edit and the formula I used. You must adapt your formula with `IFERROR` to snot show DIV/0 error

Answer (score 0):

*This solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- To find annual growth rate, the formula in cell D16:

  `=(C16-C15)/C15`
- Formula in cell D24, finds overall growth rate, *is an option exercise, you may skip it.*

  `=AVERAGE(D16:D22)`
- Enter this array (CSE) formula in cell F15, gets unique list of customers.

  ```
   {=IF(INDEX(A15:A22,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$14:F14,A15:A22),0))=0,"",INDEX(A15:A22,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$14:F14,A15:A22),0)))}
  ```
- An array (CSE) formula in cell G15, finds Customer's AAGR:

  ```
  {=IF(ISERROR(AVERAGE(IF($A$15:$A$22=$F15,$D$15:$D$22))),"",AVERAGE(IF($A$15:$A$22=$F15,$D$15:$D$22)))}
  ```

**N.B.**

- *You may find AAGR on years also.*
- *Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.*
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*